# Delta method with uniformly convergent transformation

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, weak-convergence

Let's say I have an estimator $T_n$ of $T$ and have established that
$\sqrt{n}(T_n - T) = O_p(1)$ so that $\sqrt{n}(T_n - T)$ converges in distribution to some limit $G$.

Let $f$ be differentiable around $T$. Then by Taylor+Young:
$$
\begin{aligned}
    \sqrt{n}(f(T_n) - f(T)) &= f'(T)\sqrt{n}(T_n - T) + o_p(\sqrt{n}(T_n - T))\\
                            &= f'(T)\sqrt{n}(T_n - T) + o_p(O_P(1))\\
                            &= f'(T)\sqrt{n}(T_n - T) + o_p(1)
\end{aligned}
$$
and therefore $\sqrt{n}(f(T_n) - f(T))$ converges in distribution to $f'(T)G$ by Slutsky's theorem. So far so good.

Now let's say that I in addition consider an estimator $f_n$ of $f$ and have established that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ over the domain of $T$.
That is: $\sup_{t} |f_n(t) - f(t)| = o_P(1)$

Can I then also conclude that $\sqrt{n}(f_n(T_n) - f(T))$ converges to the same limiting distribution $f'(T)G$ as $\sqrt{n}(f(T_n) - f(T))$ does?

I have tried to do the decomposition
$$
    \sqrt{n}(f_n(T_n) - f(t)) = \sqrt{n}(f_n(T_n) - f(T_n)) + \sqrt{n}(f(T_n) - f(T))
$$
where the last term now is the same as before, and the first term should hopefully  converge to zero in probability, but I am confused by the $\sqrt{n}$ factor and if the order is small enough for this to work.

What step am I missing?

Comment: The derivative $f'$ of the limit function $f$ does not necessarily equal the limit of the sequence of derivatives $\{f_n'\}$, even under uniform convergence of $f_n$ to $f$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I don't believe, however, that I have stipulated anything about the convergence of $f_n'$ here. Instead I said something about $f'$ but that's not a problem with differentiability of $f$ and weak convergence of its argument. Intuitively I'm thinking that $f_n(T_n)$ should converge much faster to $f(T_n)$ (law of large numbers) then $f(T_n)$ to $f(T)$ (central limit theorem + delta-method), so I was hoping it would work out.

Answer (score 1):

I will provide a counter-example.
Define $f(z) = z^2$, and $f_n(z) = z^2 +\frac {z}{n^{1/4}}$
Then $|f_n-f| = |\frac {z}{n^{1/4}}|$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sup_z|\frac {z}{n^{1/4}}| =0$, as long as $z$ is finite. In our case we want to examine $T_n$ as the argument of $f_n$. Since $T_n$ is an estimator that converges, I take it $T_n$ is a finite quantity for any $n$. Although we could conceive of a $T_n$ such that it becomes infinite for some finite range of $n$, it would "be a gamble" to have such an estimator. And in any case, this is a counter example that places bounds on how general the result we        seek can be -it doesn't necessarily rule it out completely. So $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$.

We examine the expression

$$\sqrt{n}(f_n(T_n) - f(T)) = \sqrt{n}\left(T_n^2 +\frac {T_n}{n^{1/4}} - T^2\right) =  \sqrt{n}\left(T_n^2  - T^2\right) + \sqrt{n}\frac {T_n}{n^{1/4}} $$

$$=\sqrt{n}(f(T_n) - f(T)) + n^{1/4}T_n$$

which diverges.
Intuitively, $f_n$ can contain terms that go to zero and allow for uniform convergence to $f$, but not at a fast enough rate compared to $\sqrt n$. The consequence is that the distance $(f_n(T_n) - f(T))$ becomes asymptotically unbounded when multiplied by $\sqrt n$. So it appears that the rate of convergence of $f_n$ to $f$ is important for the desired result.